# How to apply Proxy for the target page with PDFLib?

Tags: proxy, pdflib

I want to give reference of the pdf as a Proxy for the generated pdf. But it is not carrying the reference to the external target.
My code is as follow:

```
proxy = p.begin_template_ext(0, 0,"reference={target.pdf pagenumber=1 strongref=true}");
if (proxy == -1)
{
  /* Error */
}
```

But it always goes for error. Not sure why. Am I missing any conceptual thing in that ?
And whats the best way to use it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`PDFlib` can use one of the following objects as placeholder (proxy) for the reference page:

1. Another imported PDF page (e.g. a simplified version of the target). A PDF page which serves as a proxy for an external target must have the same page geometry as the
   target page.
2. A template, e.g. a simple geometric shape such as a crossed-out rectangle. Templates
   will be adjusted to the size and aspect ratio of the target page.

Change your code something like:

```
proxy = p.begin_template_ext(0, 0,
"reference={filename=target.pdf pagenumber=1 strongref=true}");
if (proxy == -1)
{
  /* Error */
}
...construct template contents...
p.end_template_ext(0, 0);
```

You were missing "filename" in the argument.